# ReExporting typescript class'es

Tags: typescript

Is there an effective way to re-export classes?

I would like to build a single header file that will have multiple imports from multiple classes on multiple files.

Something like:

```
import comp1= require("Component1");
import comp2 = require("Component2");
export comp1.class1
export comp2.class2
```

I know I can get the same functionality by doing

```
export class newClass extends comp1.class1 { };
```

but I want to avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your first solution. i.e. :

```
import comp1= require("Component1");
import comp2 = require("Component2");
export comp1.class1
export comp2.class2
```

Unfortunately there is no way around it except to have some code generator. (you need to create something like https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation but for AMD)

Answer (score 0):

At least in recent versions of TypeScript (e.g. version 1.8) there is syntax specifically intended to for this, e.g.

`export { RecognitionException, NoViableAltException, 
         LexerNoViableAltException, InputMismatchException, 
         FailedPredicateException } from './Errors';`